# New Battery for my Vintage MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I need a new Battery for my late 2008 MacBook but Apple consider it as Vintage so stopped producing it.

I searched my new battery on eBay and I've found two alternatives at, more or less, the same price:

- Original battery, never used but more than a year old (so it remained more than a year in his box).
- Compatible Battery, so produced by who knew with who what but most recent.

So my question is: Is better a brand new compatible battery or an original but old one?

Comment: This question seems to be primarily opinion based.

Comment: @TheBro21 Odd - I found this to be an awesome question. Remember, questions exist to invite great answers. If a question is good enough for someone with experience to make a great answer, then it's a great question.

Comment: @bmike Ok, I will bear that in mind. Sometimes it is just the speed-read taking over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lithium cells degrade over time so getting a new cell is always better three years shelf life or worse. Worse, if the part falls into deep discharge, it will be ruined. I have no issue with old batteries but I charge them up to 50% every 6 months to avoid deep discharge.

When you can get a cell that you know was put into long term storage properly, then buy from the vendor that you trust most. In this case, you're rolling the dice that the Apple part was made towards the end of the production run and not the beginning. You always have to do extra work with aftermarket parts, since some manufacturers cut corners and are even unsafe.

---

Here's Apple's take on this: http://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/

## Store it half-charged when you store it long term.

If you want to store your device long term, two key factors will affect the overall health of your battery: the environmental temperature and the percentage of charge on the battery when it’s powered down for storage. Therefore, we recommend the following:

Do not fully charge or fully discharge your device’s battery — charge it to around 50%. If you store a device when its battery is fully discharged, the battery could fall into a deep discharge state, which renders it incapable of holding a charge. Conversely, if you store it fully charged for an extended period of time, the battery may lose some capacity, leading to shorter battery life.

- Power down the device to avoid additional battery use.
- Place your device in a cool, moisture-free environment that’s less than 90° F (32° C).
- If you plan to store your device for longer than six months, charge it to 50% every six months.
- Depending on how long you store your device, it may be in a low-battery state when you remove it from long-term storage. After it’s removed from storage, it may require 20 minutes of charging with the original adapter before you can use it.

Comment: Thank you! Theoretically Apple talks of "store for longer than six months" and they didn't talk of storing time limits. Original battery I saw is new never used, so it should be stored from Apple in the best way possible... Do you think is compatible better anyway?

Comment: @Matte.Car The best way is to charge it to 50% every 6 months. Do you think someone opened that package every 6 months and charged it not to full, but to 50%. I would highly doubt so for a "new" battery. I agree they kept it cool, etc... But the problem here is no lithium battery can hold charge without a recharge for 2 years. You are gambling that the part didn't decay into deep discharge voltage levels and get ruined since it was packaged.